# Python: extract pattern from stdout and save in csv

Tags: python, csv, pattern-matching, export-to-csv

I have log files of around 20000-30000 lines long, they contain all sort of data , each line starting with current time stamp, followed by path of files/linu numbers and then value of objects added with some additional (unnecessary info).

```
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/objec: 540: Adjustment Stat
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/objec: 570: Position: 1
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/object::1150: Adding new object in    department xxxx
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/file1.java:: 728: object ID: 0
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/file2.java:: 729: Start location:1
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/file1.java:: 730: End location:55
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 728: object ID: 1
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 729: Start location:56
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 730: End location:67
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 728: object ID: 2
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 729: Start location:68
2016/08/31 17:27:43/usr/log/data/old/: 730: End location:110
Timer to Calculate location of object x took 0.004935 seconds
```

....
   ...
   ...
   Same info... for new object 
There are 30-40 object groups per file and they varies (between ID 0-3)

```
I want to extract information (next line after Adjustment Stat)and save in a text file like
Position ObjectID   StartLocation   EndLocation
           0             1              55
           1             56             67
           2             68             110
```

...
   ...
   ...

(here there isn't any object with Id 0)
    1           1           50
    2           51          109
     ...

```
Or may be store in csv file like
   0,1,55
   1,56,67
   2,68,110
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as output_file, open('in.txt') as input_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for l in input_file:
        if 'object ID:' in l:
            object_id = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
        elif 'Start location:' in l:
            start_loc = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
        elif 'End location:' in l:
            end_loc = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
            writer.writerow((object_id, start_loc, end_loc))
```

---

2.6 version:

```
import csv
import contextlib

with contextlib.nested(open('out.csv', 'w'), open('in.txt')) as (output_file, input_file):
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for l in input_file:
        if 'object ID:' in l:
            object_id = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
        elif 'Start location:' in l:
            start_loc = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
        elif 'End location:' in l:
            end_loc = l.split(':')[-1].strip()
            writer.writerow((object_id, start_loc, end_loc))
```

**out.csv** (`in.txt` as in OP)

```
0,1,55
1,56,67
2,68,110
```

Comment: logic good really good, only issue is doens't work with my olddd python (2.6)... working on converting in old python.. Thanks

Comment: builtin single line compound context managers were introduced in 2.7 - try the edited 2.6 version.

Comment: Awesome...Thanks Craig, works great with 2.6 as well, and what is more important was the way you used contextlib.nested... That'll solve lots of my other problems working on..